# How can I install Insight debugger?

Tags: 10.10, installation, debugging

I am following along a book in which Insight debugger is required. I didn't find it on my Maverick. I googled and I found that it's not supported in debian anymore but I really need to install it. I tried to compile the source and it installed but keep telling me that tk is missing whenever i start it. I installed tk with sudo aptitude install tk then tried to run again it's the same. I compiled it one more time and nothing really changes. So please how can I install that ?

Update: This is the message i get

```
Tk_Init failed: Can't find a usable tk.tcl in the following directories: 
    /usr/local/share/tk8.4 /usr/local/lib/tk8.4 /usr/lib/tk8.4 /usr/local/library /usr/library /usr/tk8.4.1/library /tk8.4.1/library

/usr/local/share/tk8.4/tk.tcl: no event type or button # or keysym
no event type or button # or keysym
    while executing
"bind Listbox <MouseWheel> {
    %W yview scroll [expr {- (%D / 120) * 4}] units
}"
    (file "/usr/local/share/tk8.4/listbox.tcl" line 182)
    invoked from within
"source /usr/local/share/tk8.4/listbox.tcl"
    (in namespace eval "::" script line 1)
    invoked from within
"namespace eval :: [list source [file join $::tk_library $file.tcl]]"
    (procedure "SourceLibFile" line 2)
    invoked from within
"SourceLibFile listbox"
    (in namespace eval "::tk" script line 4)
    invoked from within
"namespace eval ::tk {
 SourceLibFile button
 SourceLibFile entry
 SourceLibFile listbox
 SourceLibFile menu
 SourceLibFile panedwindow
 SourceLibFile ..."
    invoked from within
"if {$::tk_library ne ""} {
    if {[string equal $tcl_platform(platform) "macintosh"]} {
 proc ::tk::SourceLibFile {file} {
     if {[catch {
  namesp..."
    (file "/usr/local/share/tk8.4/tk.tcl" line 393)
    invoked from within
"source /usr/local/share/tk8.4/tk.tcl"
    ("uplevel" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"uplevel #0 [list source $file]"


This probably means that tk wasn't installed properly.
```

Answer (score 1):

Read that topic carefully
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1512700&page=2
and then add this to your repository.On my ubuntu 2.8 ultimate edition based on ubuntu 10.10 it worked!!!
https://edge.launchpad.net/~sevenmachines/+archive/dev

Answer (score 1):

Download it from here: https://edge.launchpad.net/~sevenmachines/+archive/dev/+packages*

* *only for natty,maverick,lucid*

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu tk package installs the required .tcl files into /usr/usr/share/tcltk/tk8.4, check if there is some configuration file where you can change the tcltk search path .